# For each word in a string, check if it is part of another string of words

Tags: r, string, parsing, data.table, character

I have a DT as follows:

```
DT <- fread("
ID  Sentence_1                  Sentence_2                        iso3c   year
1   This_is_an_example_sentence This_is_another_example_sentence  ARG     1983
2   The_dog_walks_in_the_park   This_is_another_example_sentence  ARG     1983
5   The_dog_walks_in_the_park   A_frisby_is_thrown_in_the_park    NLD     1984
6   I_like_soup                 A_frisby_is_thrown_in_the_park    NLD     1984",
header=TRUE)
DT$Sentence_1 <- gsub("_", " ", DT$Sentence_1)
DT$Sentence_2 <- gsub("_", " ", DT$Sentence_2)
```

I would like for each word in `Sentence_1` to check if that word also exists in `Sentence_2`. I would like to have the result of that query stored in a separate column.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
DT <- fread("
ID  Sentence_1                  Sentence_2                        iso3c   year  matching_score
1   This_is_an_example_sentence This_is_another_example_sentence  ARG     1983  4
2   The_dog_walks_in_the_park   This_is_another_example_sentence  ARG     1983  0
5   The_dog_walks_in_the_park   A_frisby_is_thrown_in_the_park    NLD     1984  3
6   I_like_soup                 A_frisby_is_thrown_in_the_park    NLD     1984  0",
header=TRUE)
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: I mean, I was considering something complicated where I first split up both strings into separate words, put them in a vector and then check how many duplicates the joined vector has. But I was I guess hoping that I am not the first person trying this and that there are some more sophisticated solutions out there. I am not very familiar with string manipulation and such.

Comment: Also my dataset is really large, and I am looking for the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DT[, `:=`(s1l = strsplit(Sentence_1, "_"), s2l = strsplit(Sentence_2, "_"))]
DT[, matching_score := sum(s1l[[1]] %in% s2l[[1]]), by = ID][, !c("s1l", "s2l")]
DT



   ID                  Sentence_1                       Sentence_2 iso3c year matching_score
1:  1 This_is_an_example_sentence This_is_another_example_sentence   ARG 1983              4
2:  2   The_dog_walks_in_the_park This_is_another_example_sentence   ARG 1983              0
3:  5   The_dog_walks_in_the_park   A_frisby_is_thrown_in_the_park   NLD 1984              3
4:  6                 I_like_soup   A_frisby_is_thrown_in_the_park   NLD 1984              0
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the capitalisation not matter in this answer (dog = Dog) ?

Comment: @Tom, yes, for example you could convert the strings to all-lowercase before splitting them up. Example: `s1l = strsplit(tolower(Sentence_1), "_")`.